# SOAP security on http operation

Tags: security, soap

I have a WSDL file and need to decide how secure it is to send data to one of the web services defined in it:

```
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SomeOperation">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://someuri.org/SomeService/SomeOperation" style="document"/>

...
</wsdl:operation>
```

I will have to send two literals there containing very sensitive data. Anyhow, I'm confused that they are using "http" instead of "https" -- I consider this as a heavy risk, or am I missing on something here?

Comment: that depends... IF the sensitive data is in itself properly encrypted it might be ok - depending on your risk scenario...

Comment: No, it's not encrypted itself (just an UUID string)

Comment: witout any information on your risk scenario etc. noone can give you a real assesment... "https" is just "transport security" - depending on your risk scenario it might or might not be an appriopriate security measure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make sure the transferred data is not visible on the wire I would prefer https for the endpoint or an otherwise secured line like a VPN underneath it.